# My kv file is a python file instead of a text file

Tags: python, file, pycharm, kivy, kivy-language

I have a main with a main class called MyApp, but when I try to create a kv text file in file->new->name: my.kv, my new created file is a python file and not a text file.

Change directory... Or create a new project.

Comment: What do you mean by "a Python file"? Python source code files are text files, by definition.

Comment: @tripleee so is my answer incorrect or unsuitable?

Comment: Hard to tell whether that's what the OP is trying to ask; they should clarify their question. Generally probably better to avoid answering unclear questions, simply because it's often not a good use of your time.

Comment: Ok I understand it,  thanks....should I leave the answer as it is?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the file which should be in `.kv` format with any text editor which can save the file as `.ky` file. For example, in Windows you can create a new text document and open it by notepad from which you can convert it into `.ky` file.

## Procedure with images:-

1. Go to the project folder, right click and hover over "New" and select `Text  Document`

[image]
2. Open the file using notepad and click on `file` on the top tool bar and select `Save As...`

[image]

3. Select `Save as type:` as all types and type the file name with `.kv` extension as end

[image]